# Link a negative in a sentence to the following word by an undercore

Tags: php, regex, nlp, tokenize

I'm trying to count the number of positive reviews on a website. Consider the following strings:

```
$str_1 = "This is great";
$str_2 = "This is not great after all";
$str_3 = "That isn't good and I will not return to this store.";
```

They mean the opposite. In automatic classification, $str_2 and 3 would be counted as positives by most classifiers (who simply count the number of positive words in a sentence). I want to circumvent this error by linking "not" with "great", "isn't" with "good and "not with "return", as follows:

```
$str_1 = "This is great";
$str_2 = "This is not_great after all";
$str_3 = "That isn't_good and I will not_return to this store.";
```

I started by tokenizing the strings:

```
$tokens = explode("", $str_3);
```

But I don't know how to proceed. How do I link the word AFTER a negative ("not", "isn't") with the following word? Isn't a regex of better use here?

Comment: i guess it is more likely to be a machine learning case.

Comment: Regex might be one component of what you're trying to accomplish, but as pointed out, it's likely not to be enough.

Comment: And as an example sentence, i want to add this: This is not bad after all. You should take negative structured positive sentences into account.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this answer's going to be very helpful, I'm afraid... If you're really trying to classify the sentiment of postings on a forum, it's an incredibly difficult problem. What you're proposing will get you some of the way there, but there's so much more complexity to the English language (and other languages) that this doesn't take into account. For example:

- I'm not kidding: this product sucks
- I can't recommend this product highly enough
- I can't recommend this product

etc. In other words, looking for a positive word preceded by a negation will work in some simple cases, but not in a lot of other cases. I think you'll want a more sophisticated approach. If you have lots of training data (i.e. manually classified reviews) you could use a neural network or a classifier like an SVM or a naive Bayes classifier.

I suspect what you'll find if you continue with the regex approach is that you'll be forever adding exceptions and special cases and it will end up being incredibly complicated and will only work in 50% of the cases. Sorry I can't be more positive!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have had the same reservations, but all the reviews I'm talking about come from Twitter messages. So their length is maxed at 140 characters. This would eliminate at least part of the problems you talk about. Also, this is a first attempt, and it doesn't have to be perfect. Sentences such as "I can't recommend this product highly enough" are probably rare. I do have to agree, though...that a regex isn't the best approach here on second thought. Do you have any other idea just to get me going? :)

Comment: Start by tokenising the string (break it into words) and then use information retrieval techniques (look up tf idf) to determine which words are the most significant ones, and then look up their sentiment (positive, negative, neutral) in a look-up table. Finally, you need to look for specific negating words ("not", "can't", "won't", etc.) coming before the main sentiment words. I'm still a bit sceptical, I'm afraid, that it will work, even with short messages, but it's worth trying! If you do have lots of sample messages, keep training it until it gets them all right (beware of overfitting).

Answer (score 0):

The "Pattern" system may be helpful for sentiment analysis, too:

- Belgian elections, June 13, 2010 - Twitter opinion mining http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern-examples-elections
- http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pages/pattern

Answer (score 0):

This one could be a start for your requirement.

https://github.com/JWHennessey/phpInsight